# Equation of a line that passes halfway between two points (in other words, divides the space)

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a formal proper way of finding the line between two points?

By that I don't mean the line connecting the two points, I mean a line that runs the same distance away from point 1 and point 2.

To phrase it another way, I want to find the equation of a line that divides the plane into two equal parts, where each of the two points are the same distance from the line.

I drew a picture. In this picture, how do I find the purple line?

[image: Line equidistant from two points]

It may or not be relevant, but I'm asking because I am trying to learn about Support Vector Machines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each point on the line has the same distance from point $x_1=(a,b)$ as from point $x_2=(c,d)$. If we say this in equations we get:
$$
(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = (x-c)^2 + (y-d)^2
$$
expand

$$
x^2 -2ax + a^2 + y^2 - 2by +b^2  = x^2 -2cx +c^2 + y^2 -2dy +d^2
$$
we can simplify and get final equation
$$
2x(a-c) + 2y(b-d) +c^2 + d^2 -a^2 - b^2 = 0
$$

---

**edit to explain in more detail first equality**

If you have two points with coordinates $X=(x,y)$ and $A=(a,b)$ than distance between them is equal to
$$
\text{dist}(X,A)=\sqrt{ (x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 }
$$
This is basically Pythagoras theorem. Draw right angle triangle with points $A,B,(x,b)$ than its hypotenuse is line segment connecting $A,B$. Pythagoras theorem calculates length of hypotenuse of right angle triangle.

In your question point on line, denote it $X=(x,y)$, has to have same distance from $A$ as well from $B$ so
$$
\text{dist}(X,A) = \text{dist}(X,B)
$$
This is almost that equation, you just need to square it.

Comment: Can you explain $
(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = (x-c)^2 + (y-d)^2
$?

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let $(x_1,y_1)$ be the coordinates of point $x_1$ and $(x_2,y_2)$ be the coordinates of point $x_2$.

The gradient $m$ of the line connecting them will be
$$m=\frac{y_2-y_1}{x_2-x_1}$$

As the purple line will be perpendicular to the line joining points $x_1$ and $x_2$ (because all points on the purple line will be equidistant from points $x_1$ and $x_2$), its gradient $m'$ will be
$$m'=-\frac{1}{m}=\frac{x_1-x_2}{y_2-y_1}$$

Now the point at which the purple line will intersect the line joining $x_1$ and $x_2$ will be the mid-point between $x_1$ and $x_2$:- 
$$\left(x_1+\frac{1}{2}(x_2-x_1),y_1+\frac{m}{2}(x_2-x_1)\right)=\left(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}\right)$$

We can find the intercept $c$ of the purple line as follows:-
$$\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}=m'\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}+c=\frac{x_1-x_2}{y_2-y_1}\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}+c
\\\Rightarrow c=\frac{(y_2^2-y_1^2)-(x_1^2-x_2^2)}{2(y_2-y_1)}=\frac{(x_2^2+y_2^2)-(x_1^2+y_1^2)}{2(y_2-y_1)}$$

Having found the intercept and the gradient, the equation of the purple line can be expressed as:-
$$y=\frac{x_1-x_2}{y_2-y_1}x+\frac{(x_2^2+y_2^2)-(x_1^2+y_1^2)}{2(y_2-y_1)}$$

Comment: Great answer, thanks

Answer (score 2):

The line goes through the midpoint of the segment $x_1x_2$ which you can find by averaging the coordinates. Its slope is the negative reciprocal of the slope of the segment. You can now use the point slope form.

Answer (score 2):

Method one (geometry):  Draw the circle, $C_1$, centered on $x_1$ passing through $x_2$ and the circle $C_2$, centered on $x_2$ passing through $x_1$.  These two circles have two intersection, $y_1, y_2$.  The line through these two points is a perpendicular bisector of the segment formed by $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Method two (algebraic):  We know that one point on the desired line is the midpoint between the two lines, $m = \frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$ and that the slope is $-1/\frac{x_{2(y)} - x_{1(y)}}{x_{2(x)} - x_{1(x)}}$, where the subscript "$(x)$" means the $x$-coordinate of the point and similarly for "$(y)$".  I.e., the desired slope is perpendicular to the rise over the run of the given points.  Assuming that the slope between $x_1$ and $x_2$ is not zero, so that the slope of the desired line is not infinity, the resulting slope is $-\frac{x_{2(x)} - x_{1(x)}}{x_{2(y)} - x_{1(y)}}$.  Putting these into point-slope form 
$$ \frac{y-m_{(y)}}{x-m_{(x)}} = -\frac{x_{2(x)} - x_{1(x)}}{x_{2(y)} - x_{1(y)}}$$ and solving this for $y$ is trivial.